# How can I change the root URL used by Url.Action()?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, url.action

My MVC C# Web Site app is installed on an internal Azure App Service with a URL like app.domain.**internal** and resolved by client's DNS and certificates with another URL "app.externaldomain.com", so final users can access the site through "app.externaldomain.com" and the internal URL keeps unknown by users.

Almost everything works fine, the problem is that when code runs an Url.Action to generate URLs, it gets the app.domain.**internal** root and I need to change or overrite that root URL for "app.externaldomain.com", so the site can generate URLs like app.externaldomain.com/controller/action instead of app.domain.**internal**/controller/action (that is not accesible for final users).

There is a way to change the root URL used by MVC to generate fully qualified URLs with a custom root instead the URL of the App Service.

It is not factible to do an "url.replace('badroot', 'rigthroot')" or something similar in all the site.

Comment: Normally that something you should configure external to your website.  Something like [Url Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that.